# Convert data from const void *data to double

Tags: c++, c, pointers, void-pointers

I received data from some other function to `myfunction(const void *data)` where pointer `data` stores the values like `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0}`.

I want to access just values from `{40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0}` and convert into a `double` type value that should give `8.0` . For accessing and conversion to double type I have tried pointer to double:

```
double* dptr;
dptr=&(*data+8);
dptr;
```

that was giving error like

> "error: ‘const void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

double myfunction(const void *data){
    double v;
    memcpy(&v, data, sizeof(v));
    return v;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char data[] = {0x40,0x20,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i, len = sizeof(data);

    //reverse data If necessary
    for(i=0;i<len/2;++i){
        unsigned char c = data[i];
        data[i] = data[len -1 -i];
        data[len -1 -i] = c;
    }
    double v;
    v = myfunction(data);
    printf("%f\n", v);//8.000000
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned @BLUEPIXY in my question i want to access values from (40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0) how can i store them automatically in some other variable and then use memcpy for that other variable will that work .. and also i<len/2 is also not clear to me please provide your valuable sugesstion in this regard.

Comment: @user3863496 There is a need to reverse the sequence of data, depending on the endianness of the machine to be used by you.

Comment: can you provide me some help because actual data i am receiving storing in const void *data is {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0} then i stored the values from {40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0} in an array let say data1 now i am having problem in reversing the values of data1 and when reversed calling myfunction because now i have stored values in data1 and my function has argument data so when i call myfunction it will call data not data1. please help me in this regard how can i resolve this issue i am much confused. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @user3863496 Names will only different.

Answer (score 2):

In C you cannot de-reference a void pointer.
So you can type cast the void pointer and use it.
something like this dptr=((double*)data+8);  So the data which is void is considered as a double pointer now.

Comment: @ Ginu Jacob i want these 8 bytes 40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0 to double value 8.0 i tried your suggestion but still having problem because confusion is when i am assigning the address of 8th element, will dptr also take the other values to provide a double type result like (0x4020000000000000) 8.0. can you please provide some suggestion..

Comment: It depends on your input array. Lets say if your array {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0} is not of double it will give you wrong results. This is because when you say a void pointer, to C it is just an address of no-sense. It considers the void pointer as the starting address and interpret the data according to the type which you are mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Your post is very unclear. Assuming `data` is actually a pointer to an array of double the solution is even simpler:

```
double * pd = static_cast<double const *>(data);
double d0 = pd[0];
double d1 = pd[1];
```

or (C):

```
double * pd= (double const *)(data);
double d0 = pd[0];
double d1 = pd[1];
```

---

You cannot perform pointer arithmetics and dereferencing on `void *` so `*data` or `data + 8` are invalid.

I don’t understand exactly what you are trying to do, but here is how you access data in your array:

Assuming the data stored is actually `int`, to access the 8th element and convert it into double you should write:

```
double el = static_cast<double>*(static_cast<int const *>(data) + 8));
```

better yet:

```
int *p = static_cast<int const *>(data);
double el = static_cast<double>(p[8]);
```

Please note that is is **really important** that you convert `data` to the original pointer type . In my example I used `int` but you should replace it with what your data actually is.

On that note, if what you are showing as `{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0}` are actually bytes, then the original pointer type is `char *` and you should convert to `char *`.

---

To clarify furthermore converting data from pointers:

Let’s say you have a pointer to `int`:

```
int i  = 24;
int *pi = &i;
```

How would you convert to double the data found on address `pi`?

```
// wrong:
double *pd = &i;
cout << *pd << endl;
```

That is wrong because what you do is converting the pointer type and not the actual data. In effect you interpret the bit pattern found at address `pi` as a bit pattern representing a `double`. But that bit pattern represents and `int`.

What you need to do is retrieve the data as it is: an `int` and then convert the `int` to `double`:

```
int x = *pi;
double d = (double) x;
```

Comment: This is not correct. If you cast to another type different of char, and add some offset (like your +8), the compiler will jump 8*sizeof(int) bytes, which will lead you outside the vector!
The correct casting for performing pointer arithmetic from a void* is ALWAYS through a char* , so the offset will be counted in bytes:
double el = static_cast<double>*(static_cast<const char *>(data) + 8));

Comment: @LoPiTaL it is correct if the data within the array is `int`. Then an element is `sizeof(int)` bytes long and the offset is correct.

Comment: @LoPiTaL Since the OP says only `void *` and then shows something like `{0, 0, 8, 0}` I don’t know what the elements are. If he is showing bytes, then yes, you should convert to `char *`, but my post is still correct as the original type of the array is `char *` and I explicitly state that he should convert to the original type. I used `int` as a placeholder.

Comment: Ok, I removed the downvote, since the OP does not explain correctly his data type. Anyway, it seems that those are bytes, since 0x4020000000000000 is actually an 8.0 value.

Comment: @LoPiTaL yeah, really bad question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform pointer arithmetic in void pointers, since you don't know the size of the inner data (as it says, it is void). You have to typecast it to a type with a known size.

The correct typecasting and pointer arithmetic is as follows (using old C conversions):

```
char * ptr=(char *)data;
double * myDoublePtr=(double *)(ptr+8);
double myDouble=*myDouble;
```

Or, as you have two doubles consecutive:

```
double * ptr=(double *)data;
double myDouble=*(ptr+1); //This will access the second double.
```

This is because an offset in pointer arithmetics will perform a jump of offset*sizeof(type) bytes, so in a char type, the number of bytes jumped will actually be the same as your offset.

Comment: my received data is bytes i want these 8 bytes 40,20,0,0,0,0,0,0 to double value 8.0 i tried your suggestion but still having problem because when i am assigning the address of 8th element, will ptr also take the other values to provide a double type result like (0x4020000000) 8.0. can you please provide some suggestion.. i want to access from 8th element that is 40 to last element and then convert whole eight elements into a double value.